# FileZilla Not Responding when accessing App_Data folder containing an MDF file

Tags: sql, asp.net, windows-10, filezilla

I am having a strange issue with FileZilla client Not Responding (Picture attached) exclusively when accessing my App_Data folder in an asp.net website which contains a mdf file (SQL Database file). The folder I'm trying to access is on my local machine. I do not have any issues with viewing any other file types.

I am running the newest version of FileZilla client (3.34.0), I have tried reinstalling. I've also tried deleting the files in AppData/Roaming/FileZilla to see if that was the issue. I've checked my crashdumps in AppData\Local\CrashDumps, and there are no dumps. I've also made sure all SQL services are not running in case the MDF file was somehow in use.

I've searched around the web, and haven't found anyone with the same issue, and as a temporary solution have to use Windows file explorer to manage my FTP for this site.

Has anyone had a similar issue, or have any ideas of what I can try next? Any help is appreciated.

[FileZilla Client not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jRMa.jpg)

Comment: If you change the .mdf extension to something else does the same file still cause problems? Is it reading the file when it has stopped responding? (You might have to use procmon to spot this) Can you build FileZilla from source and break or debug this? You might do better going directly to FileZilla for support here too.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I changed the .mdf extension, and was able to view the folder with no issues. I changed the extension back to .mdf and now FileZilla now opens and views the file with no issues - Very strange.